# CSV reader issue in Enthought Canopy

Tags: csv, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to read a csv file. The issue is that it is too large and I have had to use an error handler. Within the error handler, I have to call `csv.field_size_limit()`. Which does not work even by itself as I keep receiving a 'limit must be an integer' error. From further research, I have found that this is probably an install error. I've installed all third party tools using the Package Manager so I am not sure what could be going wrong. Any ideas about how to correct this issue?

```
import sys
import csv
maxInt = sys.maxsize
decrement = True
while decrement:
    decrement = False
    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt/10)
        decrement = True
with open("Data.csv", 'rb') as textfile:
    text = csv.reader(textfile, delimiter=" ", quotechar='|')
    for line in text:
        print ' '.join(line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: I am guessing that you are on 64-bit Windows. If so, then try using `sys.maxint` instead of `sys.maxsize`. Actually, you will probably still run into problems because I think that `csv.field_size_limit()` is going to try to preallocate memory of that size. You *really* want to estimate the actual field size that you need and maybe double it. Both `sys.maxint` and `sys.maxsize` are much too big for this.

Long explanation: Python `int` objects store C `long` integers. On all relevant 32-bit platforms, both the size of a pointer or memory offset and C `long` integers are 32-bits. On most UNIXy 64-bit platforms, both the size of a pointer or memory offset and C `long` integers are 64-bits. However, 64-bits Windows decided to keep C `long` integers 32-bits while bumping up the pointer size to 64-bits. `sys.maxint` represents the biggest Python `int` (and thus C `long`) while `sys.maxsize` is the biggest memory offset. Consequently, on 64-bit Windows, `sys.maxsize` is a Python `long` integer because the Python `int` type cannot hold a number of that size. I suspect that `csv.field_size_limit()` actually requires a number that fits into a bona fide Python `int` object. That's why you get the `OverflowError` and the `limit must be an integer` errors.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your help. The primary issue if that I don't know how to estimate the field size as the file does not open in excel (file is too large). I'll try to work around this by changing the file into text and hoping everything goes well.

Comment: You can open the file as text, iterate over the lines, and take the maximum line length. Set that as the maximum CSV field size, then reopen the file as CSV.

Comment: Ah okay. Yes, that sounds like a great idea. Thanks again Robert :)